# Compare two numbers in Javascript disregarding sign

Tags: javascript

```
if (Entry.val == data.maxPointVal)
```

So, `data.maxPointVal` is an absolute value, so it's never going to be negative, however every single `Entry.val` that isn't zero, in this case will be negative.

How do I found out if the absolute values are the same in javascript, instead of doing the compare I am doing above?

Comment: 5 almost identical answers in less than a minute. wowza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
if (Math.abs(Entry.val) == Math.abs(data.maxPointVal)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
if (Math.abs(Entry.val) == data.maxPointVal)
```

Of course do it to both sides of the `==` unless you are 100% that `data.maxPointVal` is always positive already, which you seem to be :)

Answer (score -1):

if Math.abs(Entry.val) == Math.abs(data.MaxPointVal)